# extend YouTubeProvider in SonataMedia

Tags: symfony, sonata-media-bundle

I'm using SonataMedia, SonataAdmin Bundle and YouTubeProvider to upload videos into media content.

Part of Sonata\MediaBundle\Provider\YouTubeProvider.php file:

```
//...
'cc_load_policy' => 1,
'wmode' => 'window'
//...
```

I want to change wmode to opaque. This can be done by extend YouTubeProvider.php file.

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

As there is no option specified in the [Advanced Configuration](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/master/doc/reference/advanced_configuration.html) documentation page, you will need to override the YouTube provider, and specify your Class in your `config.yml` :

```
parameters:
    sonata.media.provider.youtube: MyBundle\MyClass

sonata_media:
    providers:
        youtube:
            service:    sonata.media.provider.youtube
```